# Which actions do I configure SSL to run against in a Rails 4 app for a credit card and login use case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 or 3 instances where I want to encrypt pages in my Rails app:

- User and password creation (possibly login as well)
- Credit card subscription page

The user creation part is absolutely necessary to encrypt, for the password. The credit card page is actually only necessary from a "feel good" standpoint for conversions. Since we use `Stripe`, their JS API is served only over SSL and that traffic is always encrypted. So we never get those credit cards. But I still need to give the user the good feeling.

What I have gathered so far from documentation is that I will need to use the `force_ssl` method in the appropriate controller. And I can use `:except` or `:only` just as I do with a before_filter.

I know I will need to use the `:new` action, but do I also need to specify `:create`?

Here's what I'm starting with:

```
force_ssl unless Rails.env.development?, only: [:new, :create]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `force_ssl` for the `:create` action, this will encrypt all parameters posted to your controller action.

If you really want to make the user feel safe, you should also encrypt the login process and encrypt all pages for a logged in user.